# How to render a picture from camera view in UE 5 using the python API?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I'm trying to create a dataset from 3d models loaded in UE5, for my master's project, but the Python api documentation on UE 5 is really not helping.

I have no idea how to do. best I could do was to render a black texture which as I understand is a placeholder for the content in the camera.

I tried this that was supposed to put the image capture from the camera to the texture, somehow it just dosn't work.the add_acotr line seems to be atfault as the log give me an error saying that the camera dosn't have add_actor attribute.

```
def capture_and_save_image(camera_actor, name,resolution=(1024, 1024)):
    # Ensure the camera actor is valid and has a Scene Capture Component 2D
    if not camera_actor:
        print("Camera Actor is not valid")
        return
    asset_tools = unreal.AssetToolsHelpers.get_asset_tools()
    # Find or create a Render Target
    factory=unreal.TextureRenderTargetFactoryNew()
    asset_class=unreal.TextureRenderTarget2D
    render_target = asset_tools.create_asset(asset_name=f'{name}', 
                                                   package_path=f'/Game/SavedPics',
                                                   asset_class=asset_class,
                                                   factory=factory, 
                                                   calling_context = "name")
 
    unreal.EditorAssetLibrary.save_loaded_asset(render_target)
    
    # Attach a Scene Capture Component to the Camera Actor
    scene_capture_component = unreal.SceneCaptureComponent2D()
    
    
    camera_actor.add_actor_component(scene_capture_component, "SceneCaptureComponent")
    scene_capture_component.texture_target = render_target
    scene_capture_component.capture_source = unreal.SceneCaptureSource.SCS_FINAL_COLOR_LDR
    scene_capture_component.update_content()
```

I know it's supposed be more straight forward in c++ but Iif I can avoid learning new language just now it would save me precious time.

Comment: This is not technically an answer since I am using a different setup, but I'd suggest checking [Pixel streaming](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/unreal-engine-pixel-streaming-reference/) if you are using Linux or Windows. Then, you can capture the provided video stream. Unfortunately, I am using OS X and have to generate a video stream myself.